# higher-order function on Swift

Tags: swift

I would like to use  [this](https://github.com/mattt/Euler/blob/master/Euler.swift) project on my own, but I've tried to use every function on it, but when I get on Derivative I can't find the syntax

The original function is:

```
postfix operator ′{}
postfix func ′(function: (Double) -> (Double)) -> (Double) -> (Double) {
    let h = 1e-3
    return { (x) in
        return round((function(x + h) - function(x - h)) / (2 * h) / h) * h
    }
}
```

I found a swift 3.0 update

```
postfix operator ′
postfix func ′(function: @escaping (Double) -> (Double)) -> (Double) -> (Double) {
     let h = 1e-3
     return { (x) in
         return round((function(x + h) - function(x - h)) / (2 * h) / h) * h
     }
 }
```

but I can't find how to use it, I know it's a HOF, but maybe you could help me with the syntax?

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
let result = ({ (d:Double) -> Double in return d*d }′)(100)
```

In real life you'll probably pull it apart:

```
func f (d:Double) -> Double { return d*d }
let ff = f′
let result = ff(100) // 200
```

Comment: It Works, it returs a
"2.0"
But can you please explain how exactly it works?
What does de (100) mean Please

Comment: Ok, I think i get it, but it only returns the coeficiente coefficient right?

Comment: I'm sorry, you didn't ask what it does. You asked for the calling syntax: "may You help me with the sintaxis". That is what I demonstrated. Using it properly is up to you.